# Google Custom search API for BOTS

Tags: google-custom-search

I am creating a kind of BOT. I would like to add web search functionality to my bot. i.e. I would like my BOT to search the web for user if your says so.

To implement that I am thinking of using GOOGLE search engine. But on [overviewPage](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview#what_is_custom_search) of its [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/), it says

> Create custom search engines that search across a specified collection
>   of sites or pages.

Is there any way that this **specified collection** defaults to whole web. or is there another way round this.